# discord.py on_command_error help understanding error

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to display a message if there is an error (such as a CommandNotFound Error) when someone types in the wrong command on discord. The code I currently have is

````py
import logging
from collections.abc import Iterable


import discord
import discord.ext.commands as commands
from discord.ext.commands import cog

from bot.messaging.events import Events
import bot.extensions as ext
from bot.consts import Colors

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LINK_URL = 'https://top.gg/bot/710672266245177365'
HELP_EMBED_SIZE = 15

class HelpCog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.commands = []

    async def on_command_error(self, error, ctx):
        await ctx.send("**Invalid command. Try using** `help` **to figure out commands!**")
    
    @ext.command()
    # async def on__error(error, *args, **kwargs):
    #     await self.send_default_help(ctx)

    async def help(self, ctx, *, command_name = None):

        if command_name:
            command = self.find_command(self.bot, command_name)
            if isinstance(command, ext.ClemBotCommand):
                await self.send_command_help(ctx, command)
            elif isinstance(command, ext.ClemBotGroup):
                await self.send_group_help(ctx, command)
            else:
                await self.send_default_help(ctx, f'Command: {command_name} not found, here is a list of all my commands')
        else:
            await self.send_default_help(ctx)
    
    async def send_group_help(self, ctx, command: commands.Group):
        prefix = await self.bot.current_prefix(ctx)

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'```{prefix}{command.qualified_name}```',
                description=f'for more info on a subcommand run `{prefix}help <SubCommandName>`', 
                color=Colors.ClemsonOrange)
        embed.add_field(name='Description',value=command.long_help or 'No description provided', inline=False)

        embed.add_field(
                name='Usage Example',
                value= self.get_example(command.example, prefix) or 'No example provided',
                )

        if command.signature:
            embed.add_field(name='Signature', value=command.signature)

        if len(command.aliases)>0:
            embed.add_field(name='Aliases', value=', '.join(command.aliases))
        
        com_repr = '\n'.join(self.get_commands_repr(command.commands, f'{prefix}{command.qualified_name} '))
        embed.add_field(name='Subcommands',value= com_repr or 'No example provided', inline=False)

        embed.set_author(name=f'{self.bot.user.name} - Help1', url=LINK_URL, icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    async def send_command_help(self, ctx, command: commands.Command):
        prefix = await self.bot.current_prefix(ctx)

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'```{prefix}{command.qualified_name}```',color=Colors.ClemsonOrange)
        embed.add_field(name='Description',value=command.long_help or 'No description provided', inline=False)

        if command.signature:
            embed.add_field(name='Signature', value=command.signature)
        if len(command.aliases)>0:
            embed.add_field(name='Aliases', value=', '.join(command.aliases))

        embed.add_field(
                name='Usage Example',
                value= self.get_example(command.example, prefix) or 'No example provided',
                inline=False)
        embed.set_author(name=f'{self.bot.user.name} - Help2', url=LINK_URL, icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


    def find_command(self, parent, command_name: str):
        """
        Recursively searches the command tree to find a given command, if none found then returns None
        """
        if isinstance(parent, commands.Bot):
            found = None
            for c in parent.commands:
                if result := self.find_command(c, command_name):
                    found = result
            return found

        if parent.qualified_name == command_name: 
            return parent

        if isinstance(parent, ext.ClemBotGroup):
            for c in parent.commands:
                if result := self.find_command(c, command_name):
                    return result
        return None

    async def send_default_help(self, ctx, title=None):

        prefix = await self.bot.current_prefix(ctx)

        cog_embeds = []
        commands_str = self.get_commands_repr(self.bot.commands, prefix) 

        for command in self.chunk_list(commands_str, HELP_EMBED_SIZE):
            embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=title,
                    description=f'for more info on a command run `{prefix}help <CommandName>`', 
                    color= Colors.ClemsonOrange)

            embed.set_author(name=f'{self.bot.user.name} - Help3', url=LINK_URL, icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name='Commands', value='\n'.join(command))

            cog_embeds.append(embed)

        await self.bot.messenger.publish(Events.on_set_pageable_embed, 
                pages=cog_embeds, 
                author=ctx.author, 
                channel=ctx.channel,
                timeout=360
            )
    
    def get_commands_repr(self, commands, prefix):
        commands_repr = []
        for command in commands:
            #check to see if a command has been hidden from the public help command
            if command.hidden:
                continue
            if not isinstance(command, ext.ExtBase):
                log.warning(f'Help command invoked but none Clembot ext command found name: {command.name}, skipping command help')
                continue

            command_help = command.short_help or 'None'
            commands_repr.append(f'`{prefix}{command.name}`: {command_help}')
        
        commands_repr.sort()
        return commands_repr
    
    def get_example(self, ex, prefix, qualified_name: str= None):
        if isinstance(ex, str):
            return f'`{prefix}{ex}`'
        elif isinstance(ex, Iterable):
            return '\n'.join(f'`{prefix}{i}`' for i in ex)
        elif not ex:
            return None
        raise TypeError('Help example must be of type iterable or str')

    def chunk_list(self, lst, n):
            """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
            for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
                yield lst[i:i + n]
def setup(bot): 
    bot.add_cog(HelpCog(bot))
````

and no errors come up but the default discord message pops up instead of the desired message and this comes up in the command line

[image: command line log picture]

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work? I have tried adding @ext.command() and ext.event (ext is set to import bot.extensions as ext)

Comment: Can you add a bit more code? If you could add the whole cog it'd be awesome

Comment: Yes I'm sorry for that mistake. The whole code is not posted in the edited question. The commented out sections are some of my trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I noticed this:

```py
async def on_command_error(self, error, ctx):
```

ctx is come first before error. So it should be:

```py
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error)
```

Second, you still need an event decorator for `on_command_error`, in cog case you would use this:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
```